# How common is it to be related to another person in at least two different ways?

Tags: relationship-analysis, relatives

While exploring my genealogy, I found out that I am related to my best friend Nate via 2 different genetic routes. But a little more backstory. I was born in Texas, spent my younger years in Minnesota, and my teenage years in Florida. My best friend grew up in California his whole life.

When I joined the Army, they stationed me at Ft. Carson, Colorado. A few years after I got out of the Army, Nate moved to Colorado to try something new. This is when we met and became best friends. We never had any idea we were related until we both started looking into our ancestors.

Well, it turns out that one of my sets of great x 10 grandparents is Nate's  Nate (they were his great x 11 grandparents). When we explored more, we found that one of my sets of great x 11 grandparents was also his great x 13 grandparents. I did look up a little bit and it seems like our odds of having a common ancestor 30-50 generations back is a certainty. However, we are related in two different ways, less than 15 generations ago. How common is this sort of relation? Thank you for any help you could provide.

Comment: I suspect it's pretty common when you get that far back.  I wouldn't be surprised if my  wife is a cousin of mine (6-9th cousin), though I haven't found the connection yet.

Comment: In America I imagine its more common because its a younger country, but it's pretty common in a lot of places especially when you go further back.